# CWAC Camera - Unsure of using setCameraView()

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using CameraDemo-Layout as an example for how to properly put buttons on a screen with the camera fragment.

I'm trying to use setCameraView()

```
  /**
   * Use this if you are overriding onCreateView() and are
   * inflating a layout containing your CameraView, to tell
   * the fragment the CameraView, so the fragment can help
   * manage it. You do not need to call this if you are
   * allowing the fragment to create its own CameraView
   * instance.
   * 
   * @param cameraView
   *          the CameraView from your inflated layout
   */
  protected void setCameraView(CameraView cameraView) {
    this.cameraView=cameraView;
  }
```

but, I can't use it since it's protected. I'm using the CameraDemo - Layout as an example. I have my own CustomCam, CustomCamFragment, and CustomCamHost.

In CustomCamFragment in onCreateView I'm attempting to use setCameraView, but it is undefined. Was this by mistake or should I follow the rule "You do not need to call this..." because I don't quite understand that part?

Comment: I am trying to use CameraView directly in my activity layout without using CameraFragment, i implemented CameraHostProvider, returning SimpleCameraHost from overrided method. its not working , please anybody point me what i am missing. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but, I can't use it since it's protected

It is designed to be called from a subclass of `CameraFragment`, and a `protected` method is available to subclasses.

> I'm using the CameraDemo - Layout as an example

And you can see a call to `setCameraView()` in `onCreateView()` of [the `DemoCameraFragment` in that sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/demo-layout/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/demo/DemoCameraFragment.java):

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View content=inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, container, false);
    CameraView cameraView=(CameraView)content.findViewById(R.id.camera);

    setCameraView(cameraView);

    return(content);
  }
```

> should I follow the rule "You do not need to call this..." because I don't quite understand that part?

Either *you* are creating an instance of a `CameraView` yourself (via a constructor or layout inflation), or you are not.

If you *are* creating such an instance, *and* you want to use a `CameraFragment` subclass, that subclass must call `setCameraView()`, passing in the `CameraView` instance.

If you are *not* creating such an instance, instead allowing the stock implementation of `CameraFragment` to create a `CameraView` for you, you do not need to call `setCameraView()`, in part because you do not have a `CameraView` to set.

Comment: I have `public class CustomCamFragment extends CameraFragment` but it's not letting me access `setCameraView`. EDIT: Aha! I was importing  com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment, and that doesn't have setCameraView apparently.

Comment: @user2676468: Yes, that's a bug.

Comment: @user2676468: You can track [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/116) to keep tabs on it. I will look to release v0.6.2 tomorrow that contains this fix. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks. I may have to look into a git account instead of asking questions here. But, for now I will stick to SO.